# JSON payload error when receiving data from backend

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have set up an API that uses OAUth Mediator for generating an access token in an external backend. I'm testing the endpoint using cURL.
From enabling wire logs I see the message from cURL is received correctly, then APIM consumes external backend, which **replies with the desired information**.

However, I'm getting two errors:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
.
.
.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
```

cURL never gets a reponse and times out (Empty reply from server).

Please see attached image of the Carbon log.

Things to note:

- External API replies with content-type "application/hal-json". This is configured in my API by setting the Consumes field accordingly
- Axis2.xml has been edited to include the following lines, in their respective sections:

  ```
  <messageBuilder contentType="application/hal+json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder"/>        
  .
  .
  .
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/hal+json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
  ```
- I have two mediation policies

  In:

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <sequence name="secuenciaPrueba" statistics="enable" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
            <log description="" level="full"/>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <class name="org.wso2.apim.mediators.oauth.OAuthMediator">
                <property name="endpointId" value="EP1"/>
            </class>
        </sequence>
```

Out:

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <sequence name="secuenciaPruebaOut" statistics="enable" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
            <log level="full">
                <property name="OUT_MESSAGE" value="OUT_MESSAGE"/>
            </log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('ENDPOINT_PREFIX')" name="Endpoint"/>
                <property expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Type')" name="Content-Type"/>
                <property expression="get-property('msgID')" name="Correlation_Id"/>
            </log>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        </sequence>
```

I need to return the JSON data to cURL, what is missing here?

[image: Carbon log]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the messageFormatter and messageBuilder classes were wrong. The correct settings are:

```xml
<messageFormatter contentType="application/hal+json" 
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/> 
.
.
. 
<messageBuilder contentType="application/hal+json" 
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```